# C++11 Vector of Pointers to Templated Static Member Function

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a class that goes like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    template<typename T>
    static int Func()
    {
        // Do something with the template parameter.
    }
};
```

Now say I want to create a vector of pointers to functions with `Func`'s prototype. Since the prototype does not depend on the template parameter, it should be possible. And, sure enough, I can explicitly `typedef` a pointer to `Func`, like so:

```
typedef int (* FuncPtr)(MyStruct * pointer);
```

And then, creating the vector is as easy as:

```
std::vector<FuncPtr> FuncVector;
```

However, I would like to avoid declaring `Func`'s prototype twice. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Since as you say the prototype does not depend on the parameter, how about simply `std::vector<decltype(&Func<void>)>` ?

Comment: There is a good reason to avoid declaring `Func`'s prototype twice, when the two declarations disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `decltype`:

```
std::vector<decltype(&MyStruct::Func<void>)> FuncVector;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your `typedef` for `FuncPtr`, you could do:

```
using FuncPtr = decltype(&MyStruct::Func<int>);
```